# Pinescript Conditional Inputs

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script

In Tradingview pinescript, is there any way to make conditional inputs? Let's say I have 3 categories and each category has 3 different options:

CATEGORY1: AAA, BBB, CCC

CATEGORY2: DDD, EEE, FFF

CATEGORY3: GGG, HHH, III

The code below creates 3 input fields for the same variable 'selectoption' in the form after adding to chart:

```
selectcategory = input(title="Select Category", defval="CATEGORY1", options=["CATEGORY1", "CATEGORY2", CATEGORY3"])
if selectcategory == "CATEGORY1"
    selectoption = input(defval="AAA", title="Select Option", options=["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"])
else
    if selectcategory == "CATEGORY2"
        selectoption = input(defval="DDD", title="Select Option", options=["DDD", "EEE", "FFF"])
    else
        if selectcategory == "CATEGORY3"
            selectoption = input(defval="GGG", title="Select Option", options=["GGG", "HHH", "III"])
```

What I intend to do is to have a single field for 'Select Category' and another single field for "Select Option" in the form when the strategy is added to chart. The option list in the'Select Option' will update depending on the selected category in the "Select Category' field.

e.g. if I select CATEGORY1, the 'Select Option' field will show AAA, BBB, CCC as options; if I select CATEGORY2, the 'Select Option' field will show DDD, EEE, FFF.

I would appreciate any help or advice on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is not yet such a feature, but it's requested for future development.

Answer (score 1):

Still today, *TradingView's PineScript v5* does not have a way to create conditional *inputs*, i.e., a way to create an *input* only if a specific condition is met. Whether you put an *input* inside an *if statement* or not, the code is compiled as if the *input* was written in global scope.